Is it possible to call a VB6 form from a .NET application?
I have the following situation, one legacy (vb6) application that is currently beeing migrated to windows forms. This second solution has already many forms migrated but I would like to know if it is possible to call a vb6 form through windows forms.
I know that is possible to open windows forms through the interop library.
Thanks in advance

Directly like a library i never seen this done before. But trough using SendMessage (and a few other windows lib)you can start an application exe and hide/show window on screen, force button press and such. You can automate a full application if you have the time to spare to find the correct element to trigger.

Is your question whether a VB6 Form can be directly used in .NET code? e.g., to access its properties etc.? Or are you asking more generally how to integrate the two?

Yes I was looking for using a VB6 From in .NET code.
